# How to find all child modules in Python?

Tags: python, module, package, python-import

While it is fairly trivial in Python to import a "child" module into another module and list its attributes, it becomes slightly more difficult when you want to import *all* child modules.

I'm building a library of tools for an existing 3D application.  Each tool has its own menu item and sub menus. I'd like the tool to be responsible for creating its own menus as many of them change based on context and templates.  I'd like my base module to be able to find all child modules and check for a `create_menu()` function and call it if it finds it.

What is the easiest way to discover all child modules?

Comment: Is this related? [(`pkg_resources` from the setuptools package)](http://jeetworks.org/node/49)

Comment: Use [pkgutil.walk_packages](http://docs.python.org/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.walk_packages).

Comment: modules are not packages

Comment: as @Dag says, `pkgutil.walk_packages` can be used - it will return both packages and modules with an `is_pkg` bool flag to distinguish them. you can therefore use it to recurse down looking for your modules. however you will end up importing all the things (even the ones you're not looking for), which may not be desirable

Answer (score -2, accepted):

using [dir()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir) and [imp module](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html)

Comment: imp looks like the exact module I need!  Thanks.

Comment: That's a pretty terse answer, I don't see why it was accepted. The documentation for dir() assumes your object already has attributes. Could you elaborate and say *how* one should use dir() for finding modules not yet imported?

Comment: Nope:

`$ mkdir foo
$ touch foo/__init__.py
$ touch foo/bar.py
$ python
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import foo
>>> foo
<module 'foo' from 'foo/__init__.py'>
>>> dir(foo)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
>>> from foo import bar
>>> bar
<module 'foo.bar' from 'foo/bar.py'>`

Comment: Ross, your approach becomes unreliable when modules aren't in the file system, such as eggs.

Comment: My approach is *from* `setuptools/distribute` the *only* way you have eggs in the first place!  Seriously, read the docs, it does what you want.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov which do you think should be correct? Your short comments aren't helpful.

Comment: Sorry for being too concise. I don't know the answer, and suspect there is no good one. This one is simply wrong, though: the dir() function lists the properties of an object, and modules are not properties of a package before they are imported. I spent about 2 hours trying to figure it out, and none of the answers I could find worked (I'm working on GAE, so I don't have access to the filesystem).

Comment: this answer doesn't work, as @RossPatterson demonstrates in the comment

Comment: Neither of these can be used to achieve what the OP wanted. And it is not an actual answer, it should be a hint-like comment instead.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to do this sort of plugin thing is using [`entry_points`](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#dynamic-discovery-of-services-and-plugins) and the [API for querying them](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html#convenience-api).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Registering modules via entry points is a much more clear, deliberate, and Pythonic approach when you want to discover those at runtime, and doesn't have the side effect of causing all of them to be imported the way that `pkgutil.walk_packages` does.

Answer (score 1):

When I was a kind and just beginning programming in Python I've written this for my modular IRC bot:

```
    # Load plugins

    _plugins = []

    def ifName(name):
        try:
            return re.match('([^_.].+)\.[^.]+', a).group(1)
        except:
            return None

    def isValidPlugin(obj):
        from common.base import PluginBase
        try:
            if obj.__base__ == PluginBase:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        except:
            return False

    plugin_names = set(ifilter(lambda a: a!=None, [ifName(a) for a in os.listdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'plugins'))]))
    for plugin_name in plugin_names:
        try:
            plugin = __import__('plugins.'+plugin_name, fromlist=['plugins'])
            valid_plugins = filter(lambda a: isValidPlugin(a), [plugin.__getattribute__(a) for a in dir(plugin)])
            _plugins.extend(valid_plugins)
        except Exception, e:
            logger.exception('Error loading plugin %s', plugin_name)

    # Run plugins

    _plugins = [klass() for klass in _plugins]
```

It's not secure or "right" way, but maybe it we'll be useful nevertheless. It's **very** old code so please don't beat me.

Comment: Yes, you should use imp module like dfa mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The solution above traversing the filesystem for finding submodules is ok as long as you implement every plugin as a filesystem based module.

A more flexible way would be an explicit plugin list in your main module, and have every plugin (whether a module created by file, dynamically, or even instance of a class) adding itself to that list explicitly. Maybe via a registerPlugin function.

Remember: "explicit is better than implicit" is part of the zen of python.

Comment: for this to work you have to have a way to ensure that plugin modules are imported when you start your app, otherwise they will not get a chance to register themselves. it is chicken and egg problem. without traversing/auto importing modules you end up manually importing all the modules in your main module, negating the need for a registration function but breaking the principle that main should not need to know about specific plugins

Answer (score 1):

[`pkgutil.walk_packages()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.walk_packages) seems to be the right way to do this. Here's how I found a list of the available modules, and then imported one of them:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ touch foo/__init__.py
$ touch foo/bar.py
$ python
Python 3.8.2 (default, Jul 16 2020, 14:00:26) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import foo
>>> from pkgutil import walk_packages
>>> list(walk_packages(foo.__path__))
[ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('/home/don/git/zero-play/zero_play/foo'), name='bar', ispkg=False)]
>>> from importlib import import_module
>>> bar = import_module('foo.bar')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try `glob`bing the directory:

```
import os
import glob

modules = glob.glob(os.path.join('/some/path/to/modules', '*.py'))
```

Then you can try importing them:

```
checked_modules
for module in modules:
    try:
        __import__(module, globals(), locals()) # returns module object
    except ImportError:
        pass
    else:
        checked_modules.append(module)
```