# Python dir() not displaying all modules in a package

Tags: python, unit-testing, module, dir

I'm using python 2.6 and I'm seeing somewhat weird behavior with the `dir()` function. I'm trying to import all the modules from a directory/package for a unittest but when I do a `dir()` on on the folder, I don't get *all* the modules in that directory.

**Sample directory structure:**

```
|-mod_dir\
|---__init__.py
|---modA.py
|---modB.py
|---modC.py
|
|-mod_tests\
|---__init__.py
|---test.py
```

**Sample test.py:**

```
import mod_dir

for obj in dir(mod_dir):
   print obj
```

Unfortunately, at this point I only get something like:

```
modA
__all__
__builtins__
__doc__
__file__
__name__
__package__
__path__
```

Any ideas as to why the others aren't appearing here? I don't think it matters, but the `__init__.py` file in the mod_dir is empty. I've tried setting the `__all__` variable but it has no effect. If it does matter, however, I'm using this in WinXp with pydev in eclipse.

**Context:**

Each module under mod_dir has a unittest in it and I'm trying to include them in a unittest suite within test.py. I'm aware of nose and other methods like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555571/getting-a-list-of-all-modules-in-the-current-package/555717#555717) one, but I'm more interested in why dir isn't displaying everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it does matter that the  `__init__.py` file is empty.

Try this in the `__init__.py`:

```
import modA
import modB
import modC
```

From the python docs, [`dir` should not be used for this](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir) (see the Note at the bottom of the `dir` section). It's not rigorous enough, and mainly used in the interactive prompt.

Comment: I see. I think I'll try a different approach then. I got the idea from unittest, actually. Within one of the functions, loadTestFromModule, they do something similar, only they do a dir() on the module itself, as opposed to a package directory.