# Python package imports: What's the rule for addressing submodules?

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-pptx

I am a little confused about how python knows about modules in a packages. For example, the `python-pptx` package has a submodule `chart` whose directory structure is

```
tree /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pptx/chart
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pptx/chart
├── __init__.py
├── axis.py
├── category.py
├── chart.py
├── data.py
├── datalabel.py
├── legend.py
├── marker.py
├── plot.py
├── point.py
├── series.py
├── xlsx.py
└── xmlwriter.py
```

Now if I

```
import pptx
```

and address `chart` as

```
dir(pptx.chart)
```

then the submodules `data` and `xlsx` are missing

```
['__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 'axis',
 'category',
 'chart',
 'datalabel',
 'legend',
 'marker',
 'plot',
 'point',
 'series',
 'xmlwriter']
```

I can directly address `pptx.chart.axis` using `dir(pptx.chart.axis)` but `dir(pptx.chart.data)` results in

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'data'
```

The same thing happens if I `import pptx.chart`

But I can import `pptx.chart.data` with no issues.

What package importing rules are in place here?

### ETA

[Python dir() not displaying all modules in a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193850/python-dir-not-displaying-all-modules-in-a-package)

is a related question, but doesn't quite address what I was asking.

As explained by Alex Hall, rephrased here, some packages and modules also load other packages and modules. For example, using

```
python modulefinder.py test.py | grep pptx
```

I find that, among many other things, the following are loaded

```
P pptx.chart                /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pptx/chart/__init__.py
m pptx.chart.axis           /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pptx/chart/axis.py
m pptx.chart.category       /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pptx/chart/category.py
m pptx.chart.chart          /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pptx/chart/chart.py
m pptx.chart.datalabel      /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pptx/chart/datalabel.py
m pptx.chart.legend         /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pptx/chart/legend.py
m pptx.chart.marker         /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pptx/chart/marker.py
m pptx.chart.plot           /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pptx/chart/plot.py
m pptx.chart.point          /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pptx/chart/point.py
m pptx.chart.series         /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pptx/chart/series.py
m pptx.chart.xmlwriter      /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pptx/chart/xmlwriter.py
```

`dir` lists only loaded functions, and as `pptx` does not load `pptx.data` then `dir` does not list it. To find all potentially loadable modules, one has to use `help`

```
help(pptx.chart)
Help on package pptx.chart in pptx:

NAME
    pptx.chart

FILE
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pptx/chart/__init__.py

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    axis
    category
    chart
    data
    datalabel
    legend
    marker
    plot
    point
    series
    xlsx
    xmlwriter
```

And, if a submodule from a package is needed, one should load it explicitly and not rely on the assumption that it has been loaded by something else. Which is the rule I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When modules are imported, regardless from where, they are added as attributes to parent modules. If they are not imported from anywhere, they will not be available. This is because creating modules is an expensive process and you only want to create the modules you actually need.

Somewhere (possibly not by you directly, but by one of the modules you directly or indirectly imported) `pptx.chart.axis` was imported.

If you want to use a module, import it to guarantee it will be there. If you don't import it explicitly, it might still exist if it gets imported somewhere else, but it's not reliable.

Here is the effect in action with Django:

```
>>> import sys
>>> [x for x in sys.modules if x.startswith('django')]
[]
>>> import django
>>> [x for x in sys.modules if x.startswith('django')]
['django.utils.version', 'django', 'django.utils.lru_cache', 'django.utils']
>>> django
<module 'django' from '/Users/alexhall/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py'>
>>> django.utils
<module 'django.utils' from '/Users/alexhall/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/__init__.py'>
>>> django.core
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'django' has no attribute 'core'
>>> django.db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'django' has no attribute 'db'
>>> import django.db
>>> [x for x in sys.modules if x.startswith('django')]
['django.dispatch', 'django.dispatch.dispatcher', 'django.utils.six.moves', 'django.utils.encoding', 'django.utils.version', 'django.utils.six.moves.urllib', 'django.utils.module_loading', 'django.db', 'django.utils.six', 'django.db.utils', 'django.core.signals', 'django', 'django.utils.functional', 'django.core', 'django.utils.deprecation', 'django.utils.six.moves.urllib.parse', 'django.utils.lru_cache', 'django.conf', 'django.utils.inspect', 'django.utils._os', 'django.core.exceptions', 'django.utils', 'django.conf.global_settings']
>>> django.core
<module 'django.core' from '/Users/alexhall/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/__init__.py'>
>>> django.db
<module 'django.db' from '/Users/alexhall/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py'>
```